# Variable didn't 'stick' to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, twilio

I'm using twilio to send SMS's. If I insert my number directly `8881231234` it will work. This code below works:

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$message = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(
  '9991231234', // From a valid Twilio number
  '8881231234', // Text this number
  "Hello monkey!" //insert message here
);

print $message->sid;
```

but when I replace by adding record from database it wont work. Like below it wont work:

```
echo $row2["handset"]; // I can see my number

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$message = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(
  '9991231234', // From a valid Twilio number
  '$row2["handset"]', // Text this number
  "Hello monkey!"
);

print $message->sid;
```

I echo `$row2["handset"]` and my numbers `8881231234` appear correctly. This also didn't work:

```
$handset = '8881231234';

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$message = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(
  '9991231234', // From a valid Twilio number
  '$handset', // Text this number
  "Hello monkey!" // insert message here
);

print $message->sid;
```

Why is that? Help me please.

Comment: PHP 101: `'$row2["handset"]'` isn't a number.... note those quotes (`'`) around `$row2["handset"]`, making it a literal string... likewise quotes around `'$handset'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a variable be interpreted as a variable, use double quote:

```
$var = "$var2";
```

`$var = '$var2';` does not work as excepted.

It works with array too:

```
$var = "$var2['whatever']";
```

Or simply do:

```
$var = $var2['whatever'];
```

With concatenation:

```
$var = $var2['whatever']."suffix";
```

Well in your case you only want to do:

```
$message = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(
  '9991231234', // From a valid Twilio number
  $row2["handset"], // Text this number
  "Hello monkey!"
);
```

Comment: Thanks man it works. I was reading `http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php` and I could not find the solution. Thanks again.